Proper Wick Rotation of the Slashed Propagator: Should Gamma Matrices Be Rotated?
I'm studying fermionic propagators in quantum field theory and I'm trying to understand the correct way to perform a Wick rotation from Minkowski space to Euclidean space. Specifically, I'm unsure about how to properly handle the Dirac gamma matrices during this rotation.
Consider the fermionic propagator in Minkowski space:
$$
S_F(p) = \frac{1}{\not{p} - m} = \frac{\not{p} + m}{p^2 - m^2}
$$
where $\not{p} = \gamma^\mu p_\mu$, and the gamma matrices satisfy the Minkowski-space anticommutation relations:
$$
\{\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu\} = 2 g^{\mu\nu}, \quad \text{with} \quad g^{\mu\nu} = \mathrm{diag}(+1, -1, -1, -1).
$$
I want to perform a Wick rotation to Euclidean space, but I'm unsure whether to rotate only the momentum or both the momentum and the gamma matrices. Here are the two options I'm considering:
Option 1: Rotate only the momentum, $p^0 \rightarrow i p_E^0$, while keeping the gamma matrices unchanged. The propagator then becomes:
$$
\begin{align*}
S_F(p) &= \frac{\not{p} + m}{p^2 - m^2} \\
&\rightarrow \frac{\gamma^0 (i p_E^0) - \gamma^i p_E^i + m}{-(p_E^0)^2 - \mathbf{p}_E^2 - m^2} \\
&= -\frac{i \gamma^0 p_E^0 - \gamma^i p_E^i + m}{p_E^2 + m^2}.
\end{align*}
$$
Option 2: Rotate both the momentum and the gamma matrices, defining $p^0 \rightarrow i p_E^0$ and $\gamma^0 \rightarrow i \gamma_E^0$, where the Euclidean gamma matrices satisfy:
$$
\{\gamma_E^\mu, \gamma_E^\nu\} = 2 \delta^{\mu\nu}.
$$
Under this rotation, the propagator becomes:
$$
\begin{align*}
S_F(p) &= \frac{\not{p} + m}{p^2 - m^2} \\
&\rightarrow \frac{(i \gamma_E^0)(i p_E^0) - \gamma_E^i p_E^i + m}{-(p_E^0)^2 - \mathbf{p}_E^2 - m^2} \\
&= \frac{- \gamma_E^0 p_E^0 - \gamma_E^i p_E^i + m}{-p_E^2 - m^2} \\
&= -\frac{-\gamma_E^\mu p_{E\mu} + m}{p_E^2 + m^2} \\
&= -\frac{-\not{p}_E + m}{p_E^2 + m^2}.
\end{align*}
$$
My question is: Which method is the correct way to perform the Wick rotation for the fermionic propagator?

Should I rotate only the momentum $p^0$ to $i p_E^0$ and keep the gamma matrices $\gamma^\mu$ unchanged (Option 1)?
Or should I rotate both the momentum and the gamma matrices, such that $p^0 \rightarrow i p_E^0$ and $\gamma^0 \rightarrow i \gamma_E^0$ (Option 2)?

I'm particularly interested in understanding how the gamma matrices should be treated to maintain the correct anticommutation relations and ensure the propagator behaves properly in Euclidean space.
Any insights or explanations on the proper procedure would be greatly appreciated!
